# invoke common generic html from two different components

Tags: angular

Below is the sample code for my requirement. Here is the code snippet from app.component.html

```
<ul>
  <li><a [routerLink]="['main']" routerLinkActive="active">main</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="['report']" >report</a></li>

</ul>
<div>

</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Below is the code snippet from app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MainComponent } from '../app/main/main.component';
import { ReportComponent } from '../app/report/report.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'main', component: MainComponent },
{ path: 'report', component: ReportComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Below is code snippet from 'main.component.html'.How do i add the generic html here

```
<p>main works!</p>
```

Below is code snippet from 'main.component.ts'

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  customer: Array<Customer> = [];
  header : string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.LoadData()
    this.checkNoData();
  }

  LoadData(){
    // Customer Data ia binded to the table
  }

  checkNoData(){

     if (this.customer.length == 0){
       this.header = "Customer Details"
     }


  }
}
```

Below is the code snippet from 'report.component.html'. How do i add the generic html here

```
<p>report works!</p>
```

Below is the code snippet from 'report.component.ts'

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-report',
  templateUrl: './report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report.component.css']
})
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {

  employees: Array<Employee> = [];
  header : string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.LoadData()
    this.checkNoData();
  }

  LoadData(){
    // Customer Data ia binded to the table
  }

  checkNoData(){

     if (this.employees.length == 0){
       this.header = "Employee Details";


     }


  }

}
```

Below is the code snippet of generic template

```
<div class="alert-msg" role="alert" id="NoRecord"  >
    <div class="dsg-title"><span [innerHTML]='header'></span> </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="alert  ">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="dsg-h2"><span>No search results found.</span></h2>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Problem1. How do i integrate the generic html in the main component.html and show the generic div tags
when there is CheckNoData Function is called

Problem 2. How do i pass the value 'Header' which is set in the CheckNo Data Function.

Problem 3. is there any better approach to handle generic html in angular 9 version and latest node js

Comment: Are you asking about `@Input()`and pass data from parent to child? https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding. just can add in your components `<child-component *ngIf="condition" [header]="header"></child-component>`

Comment: No. generic html give n in the above example is not a component. It is just a generic html which i want to integrate in the another child components

Comment: I believe it can be done with ngTemplateOutlet but it is not clear how to integrate for the above example. Thanks